# How to avoid dividing by $0$ when proving the remainder theorem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial that is divided by another polynomial $x-a$, where $a$ is any real number. The remainder theorem says that remainder will be $P(a)$. One way to prove is first to note that we start with the following equation,
$$\frac{P(x)}{x-a}=Q(x)+\frac{r}{x-a}$$

Where $Q(x)$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder.

Assuming that $x-a \neq 0$, we multiply both sides by $x-a$, to obtain
$$P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+r$$

Then we let $x=a$ which gives us the result that we want,
$$P(a)=(0)Q(x)+r=r$$

But doesn't this contradict the fact that $x-a \neq 0$? It seems like we can't prove this by going to $P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+r$ from $\frac{P(x)}{x-a}=Q(x)+\frac{r}{x-a}$ since we'll be dividing by 0.

It seems like many places prove the remainder theorem this way. How do I avoid dividing by $0$ to prove this then?

Comment: This is a fundamental difference in view point. You aren't dividing by zero because $x-a$ is not zero. If it helps, it may be better to think about working in the field of rational functions.

Comment: @K02 $x-a$ takes any real number and subtracts $a$ from it, and if that real number $x$ equals $a$, then wouldn't that make $x-a = 0$?

Comment: The point is that the $x-a$ is not zero in the field of rational functions. At no point are you plugging in anything for $x$, but viewing it as an element of the field of rational functions and doing algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @K02 can you explain that in simpler terms? (for someone who's taking pre-calculus)

Comment: Simpler is this: The only way you “break” anything is if you divide by the zero object. However, “$x-a$” is not the zero object because the zero object is “$0$”. For example, people still do manipulations and write $\frac{1}{x}$ which is totally valid despite your concerns of $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is entirely fair to *start* with $P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+r$. So you can avoid the issue entirely.

But if you want to start with the fractions, then note that $$\frac{P(x)}{x-a}=Q(x)+\frac{r}{x-a}$$is not an equality of numbers. It is an equality of rational functions. And as rational functions, there is no issue, since $x-a$ is obviously not the zero function.

After multiplying with $x-a$, we get $P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+r$, which is still an equality of rational functions. Except there are no denominators any more, so it's actually an equality of polynomials. And if two polynomials are equal, then they must evaluate to the same number no matter what value you insert for $x$.

Comment: Though $x-a$ isn't a zero function (I assume a zero function is a function that maps elements of the domain to the number zero), shouldn't we consider the fact that $x-a$ may equal to $0$? Isn't deriving $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x) + r$ from $\frac{P(x)}{x-a} = Q(x)+\frac{r}{x-a}$ true only when the assumption that $x \neq a$ holds?

Comment: But I think it makes sense if we were to start from $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x) + r$, just that it confuses me a little because it doesn't really mean $P(x)$ divides by $x-a$

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Compare with integers. When $n$ is divided by $m$ giving remainder $r$ we write that as $n=mk+r$. We usually write that form immediately without the need to start from any expression with fractions. The same way we say that a polynomial $P(x)$ divided by $x-a$ leaves remainder $r$ is equivalent to the statement $P(x)=Q(x)(x-a)+r$.

Comment: @Mohammadmuazzamali Counterintuitively, in number theory, where everything revolves around divisibility, we try to avoid actual division as much as possible. So starting out with $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x) + r$ is quite natural. That being said, yes the zero function is the function that evaluates to $0$ everywhere. Among the rational functions, it is the only non-invertible element. I should caveat this with saying that at some point you will need to stop thinking of polynomials and rational functions as functions, and just think of them as pure algebraic expressions with an $x$. But that's for later.

Comment: (As an eaxmple of "avioding division", note that the definition of "The integer $a$ is divisible by the integer $b$" that we use says "There is an integer $n$ such that $a = bn$", rather than "$\frac ab$ is an integer". You can simply swap integer for anything else relevant, like polynomial, to get the definition in other contexts.)